# setOnClickListener on a second fragment layout error

Tags: android, kotlin, web

I am trying to learn from [this blog](https://maker.pro/raspberry-pi/projects/temperature-and-humidity-logger-using-raspberry-pi-with-mysql-and-an-android-app). The different was I am trying to set it the `setOnClickListener` in a fragment instead of in the main activity.

My main:

```
package com.example.testingapp

import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Variable and constants declaration
        val btnShow = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnShow)
        val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
        val btnExit = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnExit)
        val webview = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webview)
        btnExit.setOnClickListener{
            finish()
        }

        // Function that runs when the showButton is clicked.
        // It takes one argument, which is the text entered by the user.
        // Then it loads a web page, using the text as a part of the url.
        btnShow.setOnClickListener{

            // Declare the text from editText
            val text = editText.text

            // Show the text from the user in a small toast window
            Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            // Make the webView
            webview.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
            webview.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"))

        }
    }
}
```

Second fragment:

```
class SecondFragment : Fragment() {
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false)
}
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_second).setOnClickListener {
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_SecondFragment_to_FirstFragment)
    }
}
```

}

fragment_second:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/btnUpdate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context=".SecondFragment">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnExit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Exit"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnShow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="show temp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="337dp"
        android:layout_height="386dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.581"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.213" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter sensor name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnShow"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

However, I got stuck in this error and could not find out how to possibly fix this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.testingapp, PID: 10308
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testingapp/com.example.testingapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.testingapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:59)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

there is no view with `button_second` id in your `fragment_second`

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am just a bit new and could you give me some directions on fixing this?

Comment: when you do ``findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_second)``, you're getting ``null`` because there's no view (UI component) with that ID in your ``fragment_second`` layout. Which of the two buttons are you trying to add it to? You need to use the ID that you've assigned it in the XML, that's your lookup

Comment: @cactustictacs Thanks for the response! I am trying to add btnShow and btnExit. How one should match the button in the correct fragment? In that blog, it does not show one should approach that as it was just in the main....

Comment: When you ``inflate`` ``R.layout.fragment_second`` in your ``Fragment``, it's taking the ``fragment_second.xml`` layout file and creating all the ``View``s listed in there, turning them into things like ``Button``s and ``TextViews``, with all the settings you've added, including ``id``s for some. If you want to grab one of those ``View`` objects (maybe to add a click listener) you need to call ``findViewById`` with the ID of the object you're looking for. So if you're trying to set the click action for ``btnShow``, you need to do ``findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnShow)`` to get the object